# Biztalk MQSC Adapter (Value cannot be null) Error

Tags: ibm-mq, biztalk, biztalk-2016

When I try to connect IBM MQ with BizTalk 2016 and IBM MQ Client 9.0.5 version I'm getting below error message. I could not find this issues solution. Have you got any advise for this issue?

> [T149]:String.FormatHelper() : Encountered ArgumentNullException: Reason: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: format At: Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Mqsc.AbstractReceiverTask`2.ThreadProc()

---

```
  <Data>MQSC</Data> 
  <Data>Value cannot be null. Parameter name: format</Data>
```

Comment: What Cumulative update are you on?

Comment: Please share your code, and indication on which line you get the exception.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf We have CU7.

Comment: @chughts  That error looks to be coming from Microsoft code, so he won't be able to share the code..

Comment: So up to date with the latest CU.   Was it working prior to CU 7?  Or is this a new interface?  Is your Host Integration Server also on the latest CU? CU 3 I believe